# what are the various features can be added to my java application using AOP in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm a newbie to spring framework but I have to use it in my java application. I know that by using AOP(Aspect oriented programming) in spring we can achieve a lot of features.
One of them, I know about is Logging. What else are the features I can add to my java application using AOP?

I'd appreciate the help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Commons or Guava you can add hashcode/equals/toString methods to each class. But they would be reflection based, but you can always implement them yourself in performance critical classes. Aspects don't override them and the method implemented in the class would be used.

An other thing is security checks, but I never tried these.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly generic question, aop is a broader concept.

You should read [Spring AOP docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to understand how to use it.

Moreover if you want to get a better understanding of AOP in general, you can read the [AspectJ  in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988053). [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) is the AOP framework used by Spring.